# await till mongoose find operation ends to start other process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to process refunds for user when the service fails. for that, I am maintaining object of user's unique ids to later process all the refund at once using that object. here is the code :

```
Match.findById(ObjectId(match_id), async function (err, match) {
  if (!err && match) {
    user_refunds = {}
    let contests = await Contest.find({match_id: ObjectId(match_id)})

    await contests.forEach(async contest => {
      let teams = await Team.find({ contest_id: ObjectId(contest._id) })
      let user_ids = teams.map(team => team.user_id)
      user_ids.forEach(id => {
        user_refunds[id] = (user_refunds[id] || 0) + contest.cost
        console.log({ user_refunds })
        notif.newNotification(id, 'error',
                `Due to a technical difficulty, we had to cancel the match ${match.name}. A refund of ${contest.cost} coins has been issued towards your account.`, false)
      })
      // Contest.deleteOne({_id: ObjectId(contest._id)}).exec()
    })

    // match.state = 'cancelled'
    // match.save()

    console.log({user_refunds})

    User.find({steam_id: {$in: Object.keys(user_refunds)}}, function (err, users) {
      users.forEach(user => {
          user.coin_count += user_refunds[user.steam_id]
          user.save()
      })
    })
```

even though I'm using async await, second operation of adding refunds is performed prior to entries made in user_refund records.. hence nothing happens

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `.forEach` will not await the async calls that are done inside the loop. It will just fire off and not wait for the promises to resolve. This [article](https://itnext.io/why-async-await-in-a-foreach-is-not-working-5f13118f90d) explains it in detail. One way to fix this is to use a `for .. of` loop instead (do this for all `.forEach`s that do async calls):

```
for(const contest of contests) {
  let teams = await Team.find({ contest_id: ObjectId(contest._id) })
  // ...
}
```